# Копирование кода из файла (python)

Tags: python, pyautogui

Я пытаюсь скопировать код из txt файла с сохранением всех отступов и затем написать его при помощи pyautogui.

Я сделал это так:

```
import pyautogui

path = ""

file = open(path)
code = file.read()

pyautogui.write(code)
```

Однако все отступы слетают и код становится нерабочим. Я также попробовал разделить текст на строки и записать его построчно, но результат это не поменяло. Как я могу решить это проблему?

Comment: если открываете файл через open, то не забывайте закрывать файл: "file.close()". Если не хотите заморачиваться когда открыть и когда закрыть - используйте "with open(...) as ...."

Answer (score 0):

@ILSD, исправил на автоматическое закрытие файла после открытия и явно указал на чтение. У меня сработало. В Вашем коде не видно, что делаете с файлом, может Вы устанавливаете режим записи - в таком случае все данные будут удалятся из этого файла.

```
import pyautogui

path = "test.txt"

with open(path, 'r') as file:
    code = file.read()

pyautogui.write(code)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: По умолчанию `open` открывает файлы в режиме текстового чтения: `open(file, mode='r', ...`